# Fix broken dependency on Ubuntu 22.04 - mysterious libnvidia-nscq does not allow update or installation of existing packages

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with Nvidia 515.86.01 (proprietary), along with the CUDA toolkit and cuDNN.

```
nvidia/515.86.01, 5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64
```

After 3 weeks of holiday I am back and wanted to install a few tools (Evince for example). I was surprised to see that nothing regarding `apt-get` related to package installation or upgrade works due to a mysterious `libnvidia-nscq`:

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree...
Done Reading state information...
Done You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libnvidia-nscq-510 : Depends: libnvidia-nscq-515 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

From what I can tell

- NSCQ is a NVswitch, which is something from Nvidia regarding servers and GPUs
- Version 510 is a transitional package

Running `dpkg -l *nvidia*` returns the following (among others)

```
iU  libnvidia-nscq-510                  515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-nscq-515
in  libnvidia-nscq-515                  <none>                     amd64        (no description available)
```

I cannot figure out where this NSCQ dependency is coming from. In addition it is rather strange that 510 depends on 515 but perhaps I've misunderstood this line.

```
apt-cache depends libnvidia-nscq-515
libnvidia-nscq-515
  Conflicts: <libnvidia-nscq>
    libnvidia-nscq-450
    libnvidia-nscq-470
    libnvidia-nscq-525
  Replaces: <libnvidia-nscq>
    libnvidia-nscq-450
    libnvidia-nscq-470
    libnvidia-nscq-515
    libnvidia-nscq-525
```

I can neither run `apt-get upgrade`, nor `apt-get autoremove`, nor `apt-get install <package>`. I did `apt-get clean` to remove the cached packages and then pulled fresh ones using `apt-get update`.

If I am to remove the Nvidia drivers and CUDA toolkit, I am pretty sure it will break my machine learning setup (PyTorch and TensorFlow). These tools are very fiddly when it comes to which version of driver/CUDA/cuDNN is to be used.

**UPDATE:**

As per request in the comments:

```
apt policy libnvidia-nscq-515

libnvidia-nscq-515:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
     515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition is a little confusing, because in 22.04, `libnvidia-nscq-510` is in multiverse, but `libnvidia-nscq-515` is in restricted. To successfully upgrade, you need to enable the restricted repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have enabled `restricted` (using `add-apt-repository restricted`) but the issue persists. How come I cannot find the mentioned package being installed?

Comment: Did you run `apt update` after enabling the repository?

Comment: :D I did. It actually does it automatically right after I added the repository (cool). Also wiped the APT cache just to be sure.

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/730657/edit) to show the output of `apt policy libnvidia-nscq-515`?

Answer (score 0):

For now I was able to solve the issue (will not be surprised if some random issue pops up in due time) by manually installing the required package from `/var/cache`, which was displayed by the failing APT:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-nscq-515_515.86.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb
```

I didn't get any errors and I was upgrade/install other packages (not related to the above mentioned one) without any noticeable issues.